# SwiftUI: How to retrieve data from Firestore in second view?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, picker

This is my first SwiftUI project and am very new in programming.

I have a View Model and a picker for my Content View, manage to send $selection to Detail View but not sure how to get it to read from the Firestore again. I kinda feel like something is missing, like I need to use an if-else, but can't pinpoint exactly what is the problem. Searched through the forum here but can't seemed to find a solution.

Here is the VM

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class FoodViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var datas = [Food]()

private var db = Firestore.firestore()

func fetchData(){
    
    db.collection("meals").addSnapshotListener { (snap, err) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if err != nil {
            print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
            return
        } else {
        for i in snap!.documentChanges{
                
                let id = i.document.documentID
                let name = i.document.get("name") as? String ?? ""
                let weight = i.document.get("weight") as? Int ?? 0
                let temp = i.document.get("temp") as? Int ?? 0
                let time = i.document.get("time") as? Int ?? 0
                
                
                self.datas.append(Food(id: id, name: name, weight: weight, temp: temp, time: time))
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
struct ContentView: View {

@ObservedObject var foodDatas = FoodViewModel()

@State private var id = ""
@State public var selection: Int = 0

var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView{

        let allFood = self.foodDatas.datas

        ZStack {
            Color("brandBlue")
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                Picker(selection: $selection, label: Text("Select your food")) {
                    ForEach(allFood.indices, id:\.self) { index in
                        Text(allFood[index].name.capitalized).tag(index)
                    }
                }
                .onAppear() {
                    self.foodDatas.fetchData()
                }

                Spacer()
                
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: DetailView(selection: self.$selection),
                    label: {
                        Text("Let's make this!")
                            .font(.system(size: 20))
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                            .padding(12)
                    })
}
```

And after the picker selected a food type, I hope for it to display the rest of details such as cooking time and temperature. Now it is displaying 'index out of range' for the Text part.

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct DetailView: View {

@ObservedObject var foodDatas = FoodViewModel()

@Binding var selection: Int


var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView{
        
        let allFood = self.foodDatas.datas
        
        ZStack {
            Color("brandBlue")
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                
                Text("Cooking Time: \(allFood[selection].time) mins")
                
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Appreciate for all the help that I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `DetailView`, you're creating a new instance of `FoodViewModel`:

```
@ObservedObject var foodDatas = FoodViewModel()
```

That new instance has not fetched any data, and thus the index of the selection is out of bounds, because its array is empty.

You could pass your original `ContentView`'s copy of the `FoodDataModel` as a parameter.

So, the previous line I quoted would become:

```
@ObservedObject var foodDatas : FoodViewModel
```

And then your `NavigationLink` would look like this:

```
NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(foodDatas: foodDatas, selection: self.$selection) //... etc
```

Comment: Thanks, it fetches the data now! Noted about my mistake, thanks again.